# Is $scope dependecy injection in AngularJS controller definition?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

All:

What confused me about dependency injection in AngularJS is its concept(I guess I have still not get the whole idea of DI):

I wonder how to tell which are dependencies that should be(and can be) injected?

For example:

If I define a controller and directive:

```
app.controller("maincontroller", ["$scope", "dependency1", function($scope, dependency1){

}])

app.directive("dir1", ["dependency2", "dependency3", 
                       function(dependency2, dependency3){
    return {
         restrict: "AE",
         scope:{},
         controller: function($scope){},
         link:function(scope, EL, attrs, ctrl){}
    };
}])
```

I wonder why I need to inject $scope as dependency in controller, but no need to do that in directive definition. And what is more: if I put $scope in that directive function, it will gives me an error:

```
Error: error:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- dir1Directive
```

**[1]** Is this $scope a dependency, or **[2]** my understanding about dependency is totally wrong(someone told me that $scope is not a dependency) or **[3]** my understanding about directive def function is wrong(only service can be put in directive def function)?

If my wrong is the last one, then how many type of dependencies does AngularJS have?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `$scope` isn't actually a service !

This is why you don't have to pass it as a dependency of the directive. `$scope` is a local passed to the injector, a value passed to the function, as if i would do `console.log(myValue)`. `myValue` is not a service.

The `$injector`'s `invoke` method, which passes services to a function, can replace a requested dependency by a given value, see [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#invoke) for more details. I recognize that mixing services and simples values in the arguments list are confusing, as we can't know which one are the services and which one are simple arguments, but it works that way.

We can consider that something like this is executed when a new controller is instanciated :

```
var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
$injector.invoke(controller, context /*the this binding*/, {
    $scope: $rootScope.new()
});
```

See also [the code of the controller service](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/controller.js) for further details.

### Update : difference between `$scope` and services

Take this function :

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

`a` and `b` are "simple arguments", they are the values on which the function perform calculations. Imagine that you want to broadcast a message to your app that an addition just have been performed. In Angular, we can use the `$rootScope.$broadcast` method.

```
function add(a, b) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addition.done', a + b);
    return a + b;
}
```

But here, `$rootScope` has never been declared. We have to load the `$rootScope` service in our function. Angular uses the `$injector.invoke` method in order to do this : it takes a function or an array (the "square bracket" notation), *extract the services names from the function* arguments/array elements, and *calls the function with the corresponding services* passed as arguments.

```
function add(a, b, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addition.done', a + b);
    return a + b;
}

var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']); // Creates the injector, with the services of `ng` module.
$injector.invoke(add); // Calls the function with the requested services
```

It will throw an error, because `a` and `b` aren't services. In fact, they don't have to be services, because they are values that we want to set ourself. For the injector, they are **locals**. In order to perform the addition of `2` and `3` with the `add` function, we have to do the following :

```
function add(a, b, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addition.done', a + b);
    return a + b;
}

var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
$injector.invoke(add, this, {
    a: 2, // When requesting the `a` service, return the value `2`
    b: 3 // The same here, with `b` and `3`
});
```

The same is done with controllers. `$scope` itself is not a service, but a new scope, build each time the directive is loaded. Like `a` and `b`, the newly created `$scope` is *a value on which the function perform some logic and modifications*. **`$scope` is not a dependency, but an argument of the function.** And because the `$injector` extracts the dependencies from the arguments list, we can't tell if an argument is a service or not (except if you  already know it, but this isn't an evidence). Here, `$scope` *is not a service*, and is also the same object that in the `link` function in your directive. Note the fact that the documentation does not name the scope argument `$scope`, but `scope`. If `scope` was a service, it would throw an error, but actually it doesn't, because the `link` function isn't called with `$injector.invoke`.

Comment: thanks for reply.  I got the "isn't actually a service !" part, but not get the part of "This is why you don't have to pass it as a dependency", does this mean the $scope is not considered as a dependency and it is just accidentally used in same format with other injected dependencies? And the  square brackets syntax is just for minification purpose rather than means all put into it should be dependencies. And other than that, it has no relationship with dependency injection?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope it helps you understand what I'm trying to explain :)